# Replace in-string characters with regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

i'm pretty unconfident with regex and i need to do this simple work:
i have an input string like this:

```
<a id="randomid">some text ( +1 even more text)</a>
```

now i need to replace that "1", i know it will always be between `( +` and a space, how can i do this with regex?

That string is generated by ASP.NET inside a `asp:HyperLink` component, my first try was to generate that number inside a `<span>` with know id, but looks like *asp.net* remove all my html tags inside a *ASP* component

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using jQuery...

```
$('a#randomid').text().replace(/(.+ \( \+)([0-9]+)(.+)/, "$12$3")
```

Will give you...

```
some text ( +2 even more text)
```

Comment: seems like is not working :( i'm sure the input string is correct, i used a console.log($('a#randomid').text()) and output is right but it doesn't replace the number :(

Comment: Using "some text ( +1 even more text)".replace(/(.+ \( \+)([0-9]+)(.+)/, "$12$3") in Chromiums console I get "some text ( +2 even more text)". Works for me.

Comment: .. in console works even with me :\ ok i mark this as correct answer, thank you! now i have to figure out why it doesn't work in my code :P

Comment: ok i was pretty dumb, i was just omitting the "$('#myid').text() = " eheh, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If your assumption is correct, this will also work for you, it will replace the first occurance of "( +number" with "( +replaceNumber".

```
var regex = /\(\s+\+[0-9]+/
var replaceNumber = 2;
$('a#randomid').text().replace(regex, "( +"+replaceNumber);
```

TO replace all the occurances change the regex to

```
var regex = /\(\s+\+[0-9]+/g
```